# Demi dodecahedron - what is it?

Tags: polyhedra

What is a demi dodecahedron? I have not been able to find the geometry of a demi dodecahedron.

From latin, what makes a polygon a demi dodecahedron?

Can a demi dodecahedron possibly contain 9 faces? I have to document a complex structure that is said to be derived from one of these polygons but so far I have been unable to encounter much information on it.

Comment: you need to give some detail, links to articles involved, what have you. It is easy enough to make a solid with nine faces if you allow a mixture of things, triangles and what have you. A pyramid on an octagonal base has nine faces.

Comment: Are you by any chance talking about a [hemi dodecahedron](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hemi-dodecahedron)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you cut a regular dodecahedron in half, it looks to me like you can get 10 or 12 faces easily.  If you bisect the diagonal from one vertex to the opposite you cut off three of the original faces, leaving 9, and add your new plane for 10.  If you cut it parallel to two faces you cut off one pentagon, but get parts of 10 faces, one whole pentagon, and the cut face for 12.  I don't think it is half volume, but it looks like you could cut it perpendicular to the line joining the midpoints of opposite edges and cut off four faces plus add your cut for 9.